# How can I change the TLS version to 1.1 via cPanel terminal?

Tags: ssl, server, configuration, cpanel

I would like to change the TLS version to 1.1, so my Windows 7 OS can access my REST API without getting an SSL error.

I checked out the SSL/TSL panel, but it doesn't let me change the cipher/version. Is it possible to do via terminal?

Comment: Windows 7 should be able to do TLS 1.2 which is likely enabled by default on your server (there would be no security reason to disable it - it is considered secure). What kind of SSL error do you even get and why do you think it is related to the protocol version?

Comment: We have done requests from a Windows 10 system and it worked perfectly fine, until we tested it on Windows 7. The Error I am getting is: curl_easy_perform<> failed: SSL connect error

Comment: *"... curl_easy_perform ..."* . Ah, this is about curl on Windows 7, not Windows 7 in general. Please include in your question the full output of `curl -v ...`  to get more debug information from the connection attempt and also the output from `curl -V` to get the version information. Also, try to reach the site with a browser on Win7 instead of curl.

Comment: We also tried to change Windows 7 to TSL 1.2, by changing the regedit values, but that didn't change the output. libcurl has been linked to the .exe and sent over to the Windows 7 OS. Should I install curl on windows 7 and run the command lines you have sent me?

Comment: curl (and libcurl) does not necessary use the Windows TLS library (SChannel) and thus does not use the OS settings regarding TLS. You might try to install curl on Windows but make sure that it is the same version as used in your app and with the same settings regarding the TLS backend. Otherwise the results from one are not relevant to the other. You might also try to make a packet capture of the TLS connection with wireshark so that one can have a closer look at it what your app is actually doing.

Comment: We have done some testing and send requests to other endpoints and tested various TSL  versions (TSL 1.0 - 1.2) and they all worked. The issue is that we are using shared hosting and the TSL version is much higher than Windows 7 can have.

Comment: First, it is "TLS" (Transport Layer Security) and not TSL. I've corrected it already in your question. Then again - depending on how curl/libcurl is compiled it does not use the TLS library from Windows but something like OpenSSL, GNUTLS, NSS, ... - in which case the Win7 settings have no effect. *"send requests to other endpoints and tested various TSL versions (TSL 1.0 - 1.2) and they all worked"* - if your app works with other systems and TLS 1.2 then why doesn't it work with your endpoint and TLS 1.2, i.e. why you do you want to use TLS 1.1?

Comment: Oh, I was writing it wrong all the time, thanks a lot! We found out that our host only accepts the newest cipher suites for tls1.2. That's why we can make requests to other websites, but not to our REST API from Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for helping us, but unfortunately Windows 7 doesn't support the cipher that is needed. We have to change the host.